# Trying to read bitmap file as hexadecimals

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NBRCOLOURS 16
#define COLOURSIZE 8

typedef struct
{
    char colours[COLOURSIZE];

}BITMAP;



//Main Function
void main(void)
{
    int count, count2;
    char bm_file[] = "C:\\Coding\\Bitmap Program\\Sample.bmp";
    FILE *fptr;
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    BITMAP bm_data[NBRCOLOURS];


    fptr = fopen(bm_file, "rb");
    if (fptr != NULL)
    {
        while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
        {
            printf("%02X ", ch);
            if (!(++i % 16)) putc('\n', stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

I am using this code which I found mostly online to try and read the contents of a bitmap file as its hexadecimal values.  For some reason, this code stops right at the end of the header, and unfortunately ultimately I need to count the number of times each colour appears so that I can figure out which occurs most and which occurs least.

If anyone could tell me why this code stops at the end of the header for the bitmap, or lead me towards being able to pull the rest of the hexadecimal data out of the file, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the hex code:

```
42 4D C6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 00 00 00 28 00 
00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 
00 00 50 00 00 00 12 0B 00 00 12 0B 00 00 10 00 
00 00 10 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 
42 00 5A 5A 84 00 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 FF 
FF 00 08 FF FF 00 5A FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF 
FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF 
FF 00 FF FF FF 00 92 59 00 16 47 00 00 00 25 90 
01 64 61 00 00 00 59 90 11 64 61 00 00 00 99 00 
16 48 11 00 00 00 90 01 64 61 11 00 00 00 00 16 
64 61 00 00 00 00 01 16 46 10 09 00 00 00 11 64 
41 00 99 00 00 00 16 64 11 09 95 00 00 00 66 48 
10 09 53 00 00 00
```

And here is what prints:

```
42 4D FFFFFFC6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 00 00 00 28 00 
00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 
00 00 50 00 00 00 12 0B 00 00 12 0B 00 00 10 00 
00 00 10 00 00 00
```

Long post, I'm sorry. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fgetc` returns `int` (not `char`) for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

fgetc returns an int, not a char.  You can't represent EOF with a char, as all of the possible values of a char are valid.  EOF is (I think) -1 represented as an int, or 0xfffffff, so if you read 0xff as a char it's the same as EOF.

Change this:

```
char ch;
```

to:

```
int ch;
```

Comment: The C standard only says `EOF` is negative. But yeah, I've never seen a platform that doesn't make it `-1`.

Comment: "You can't represent EOF with a `char`" That's not correct if `char` is signed like typically on x86 (but not ARM) and `-1` like on many platforms.

Comment: (Splitting hairs department. :-))  Whether or not char is signed, casting -1 to a char will produce a valid char value, either -1 or 255.  I suppose if you're working with a 7-bit ASCII text file it would be distinct (neither -1 or 255 are valid 7-bit ASCII), but the sign wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The number before a format specifier in `printf`, like `%02X` only guarantees a *minimum* number of characters outputted, not a maximum. `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  If the `int` is negative two's complement then the entire bitstring representing the int will get printed, including the `FF` bytes at the start.  `EOF` is not representable as a `char`; only as an `int`.

In your case we know that the file we're working with is small enough that loading the entire file into a buffer will probably succeed, so we can just use `malloc` and `free` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef unsigned char byte;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Coding\\Bitmap Program\\Sample.bmp", "rb");
    byte *buffer = NULL;
    size_t len;
    int i;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    len = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    buffer = malloc(len);
    if(!buffer)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(buffer, 1, len, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(i%16==0) putchar('\n');
        printf("%.2X ", buffer[i]&0xFF);

    }
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```